# Adding Information in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am having trouble with my Android App when adding information into SQLite. I am relatively new to Java/SQLite and though I have followed a lot of tutorials on SQLite and have been able to get the example code to run I am unable to get tables to be created and data to import when running my own app. I have included my code in two Java files Questions (Main Program) and QuestionData (helper class represents the database).

Questions.java:

```
public class Questions extends Activity {
private QuestionData questions;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.quiztest);
questions = new QuestionData(this);
try {
Cursor cursor = getQuestions();
showQuestions(cursor);
} finally {
questions.close();
}
}

private Cursor getQuestions() {
//Select Query 
String loadQuestions = "SELECT * FROM questionlist";
SQLiteDatabase db = questions.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(loadQuestions, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
return cursor;
}

private void showQuestions(Cursor cursor) {
// Collect String Values from Query and Display them this part of the code is wokring fine when there is data present.
```

QuestionData.java

```
public class QuestionData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TriviaQuiz.db" ;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public QuestionData(Context ctx) {
super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE questionlist (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, QID TEXT, QQuestion TEXT, QAnswer TEXT, QOption1 TEXT, QOption2 TEXT, QOption3 TEXT, QCategoryTagLvl1 TEXT, QCategoryTagLvl2 TEXT, QOptionalTag1 TEXT, QOptionalTag2 TEXT, QOptionalTag3 TEXT, QOptionalTag4 TEXT, QOptionalTag5 TEXT, QTimePeriod TEXT, QDifficultyRating TEXT, QGenderBias TEXT, QAgeBias TEXT, QRegion TEXT, QWikiLink TEXT, QValidationLink1 TEXT, QValidationLink2 TEXT, QHint TEXT, QLastValidation TEXT, QNotes TEXT, QMultimediaType TEXT, QMultimediaLink TEXT, QLastAsked TEXT);");

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO questionlist (_id, QID, QQuestion, QAnswer, QOption1, QOption2, QOption3, QCategoryTagLvl1, QCategoryTagLvl2, QOptionalTag1, QOptionalTag2, QOptionalTag3, QOptionalTag4, QOptionalTag5, QTimePeriod, QDifficultyRating, QGenderBias, QAgeBias, QRegion, QWikiLink, QValidationLink1, QValidationLink2, QHint, QLastValidation, QNotes, QMultimediaType, QMultimediaLink, QLastAsked)"+
"VALUES (null,'Q00001','Example','Ans1','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Any suggestions at all would be great. I have tried debugging which suggests that the database does not exist. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Please use the {} button to format your question a bit. Further more: what goeds fwrong? where? what are the errors you're getting?

Comment: Apologies just fixed the formatting I have the Question Activity attached to a button in the interface, when it is run the screen goes black and the force close error appears.

Comment: you should be able to see the error and stacktrace in the debugging view in Eclipse, that info would be helpful.

Comment: Is TABLE_NAME defined correctly? The declaration is not shown, and it would be better to use it in the CREATE TABLE and INSERT as well as the DROP TABLE, or don't use it at all.

Comment: Thanks Luke and everyone else who contributed I removed the constants setup which had a capitalisation in it which was not referenced elsewhere. I knew it was going to be something simple but I could not locate the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the constants setup which had a capitalisation in it which was not referenced elsewhere. I knew it was going to be something simple but I could not locate the issue. Thanks again!